# Change parent state on a child envent

Tags: reactjs

I want to put all my 'isSelected' to false expect the clicked one.
Code :

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state= {
        menu:[
            {isSelected:true},
            {isSelected:false},
            {isSelected:false}
        ]
    }
    render() {
        let menus=this.state.menu.map((menu,i)=>(
            <MenuElem isSelected={menu.isSelected} />
        ))

        return 
        {menus}      
        );
    }
}

class MenuElem extends Component {
    state = {
        isSelected: this.props.isSelected
    }
    render() {
        const {isSelected} = this.state;
        let clickHandler = ()=>{
            this.setState({ isSelected: true })
            //I want to put all the MenuElem to false : except the clicked one
            // let parent = this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance; ??
            // then foreach MenuElem in my parent I change the isSelected ?
        }
        return (
            <li onClick={clickHandler} className={isSelected ? "is-active" : ""}></li>
        );
    }
}
```

I'am not sure my logic is the good one.
The this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance looks like Im in the wrong way.

Comment: The problem in your use case is that isSelected requires all children to have knowledge of the selected instance when rendering. I recommend that you keep track of the selected child (by id) in the parent's state and check against that when rerendering the children (you could pass it down as a prop from the parent)

Comment: I can edit a parent props from a children ?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/409/how-to-update-parent-state-from-child-component-in-react

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of cleaning that could be done to this code but below I rewrote what you had and allowed the child to update the parent's state. I trust you have a valid reason to do this and not manage the state of the `li` at the `li` level. Hope this helps.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        menu:[
            { isSelected: true },
            { isSelected: false },
            { isSelected: false }
        ]
    }
    render() {
        const { menu } = this.state;
        return (
            { menu.map((menu,i) => {
                return <MenuElem 
                    isSelected={menu.isSelected} 
                    onClick={() => {
                        const newMenu = [...menu];
                        newMenu[i] = !menu[i]
                        this.setState({ menu: newMenu }) }
                    }
                />
            })};
        );
    }
}

class MenuElem extends Component {
    render() {
        const { onClick, isSelected } = this.props;
        return (
            <li onClick={onClick} className={isSelected ? "is-active" : ""}></li>
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: In the case where you don't really need the state stored in the parent you could just as easily do:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            { menu.map((menu,i) => <MenuElem key={i}/> }
        );
    }
}
class MenuElem extends Component {
    state = { isSelected: false }
    render() {
        const { isSelected } = this.state
        return (
            <li onClick={() => {this.setState({ isSelected: !isSelected })}} className={isSelected ? "is-active" : ""}></li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: mmh, thanks, seems i didnt get somethink : I have no reason to dont do it in the li

Comment: ```onClick={() => {this.setState({ menu: !menu[i] }) }}``` This will just delete my Menu array